# Facing issue when I try to get suggestion in function parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My function have to receive one of  fixed five types of string like "success, error, warning, info, question". So that I write function like this:

```
export const notify = (type: 'success' | 'error' | 'warning' | 'info' | 'question' ,message)=>{
  // some code
}
```

In that case I am facing this error : `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (7:27)`
[image]

Same thing I did my another project without any problem.
[image]
But now what did I wrong, I cant figure it out.
please help me.

Comment: isn't this format for typescript validations and we can only do it in `.ts` files

Comment: You seem to be using typescript inside a JavaScript file. Did you mean to name the file `notifications.ts` instead?

Comment: Where I did the same thing I added in the question. please check

Comment: Same issue. You're using typescript in a JS file. If you tried to run `alerts.js` you should see a syntax error.